# How to prevent user from scrolling while implementing swipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh, pull-to-refresh

In my app I have a recycler view with 20 - 30 items and I have the function to pull to refresh the content, and I want to prevent the user from scrolling the view while the refresh is in progress because it creates an error if the user ties to scroll and the regresh is in progress, but I'm really lost on how to do it :/

```
eRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        eRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);

 swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refreshSecondLevel);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() { 
               loadNewContent();
               Handler delay = new Handler();
                delay.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() { 
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override [`canScrollVertically`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#canScrollVertically()) method on your `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`:

```
public class ToggledScrollLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean mIsScrollEnabled = true;

    public ToggledScrollLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScrollEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.mIsScrollEnabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return mIsScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```

Then use it when user refreshed the page:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
ToggledScrollLayoutManager layoutManager = new ToggledScrollLayoutManager();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refreshSecondLevel);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
        public void onRefresh() { 
            loadNewContent();
            layoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false);
            Handler delay = new Handler();
            delay.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    layoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, only small thing, I using RecyclerView.LayoutManager vLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2), and Im truing to change LinearLayoutManager  to GridLayoutManager but I gt an error on ToggledScrollLayoutManager(Context context)

Comment: I have upadted my question with a more details, thanks bro!

Comment: @CarlosCastro just inherit your layout manager from `GridLayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager` and add the matching constructors.

Comment: I'm trying vLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false); and i gt the error " cannot resolve method setScreollenable" any ideas why ?

Comment: Pay attention to the letters, there has to be no typo errors in your code to run. The method name has to be exactly `setScrollEnabled`, case sensitive.